# iOS - How do you get past permissions in UI tests?

Tags: ios, swift, xctest

I'm facing with a stuck when try dismiss alert system on XCTest.
Before that everything was fine when i used com.apple.springboard or addUIInterruptionMonitor to get Accept button, but the last few months it can't work when call tap() and throw the error
[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil (NSInvalidArgumentException).

Could someone give me a solution? Many thanks.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Restarting the iOS device resolved the issue in my case